# Regexp match mandatory words and word sequences

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match a string that containing mandatory words or words sequences with repetitions. I even don't know if I can do that with a Regexp.

Example string

```
No depending be convinced in unfeeling he. 
Excellence she unaffected and too sentiments her. 
Rooms he doors there ye aware in by shall. 
Education remainder in so cordially. 
His remainder and own dejection daughters sportsmen. 
Is easy took he shed to kind.
```

Mandatory words

```
Rooms (1x)
Excellence (2x)
Education (1x)
House (1x)
```

Should return something like

```
Success: false

Rooms: 1
Excellence: 1
Education: 1
House: 0
```

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var requiredWords = {
  Rooms: 1,
  Excellence: 2,
  Education: 1,
  House: 1,
};

var success = true;
for(var word in requiredWords){
  var requiredAmount = requiredWords[word];

  //create and check against regex
  var regex = new RegExp(word, 'g');
  var count = (yourString.match(regex) || []).length;

  //if it doesn't occur often enough, the string is not ok
  if(count < requiredAmount){
    success = false;
  }
}

alert(success);
```

You create an object with all required words an the needed amount, then  loop through them and check if they occur often enough. If not a single word fails, the string is OK.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fon7akb0/)

Comment: Hey thanks that's what exactly what i was coding right now! Thanks for your time

Comment: can I ask you smtg else?

If I have 2 mandatory "strings" like 
 - my name
 - name

and a sentence like 'my name is john'

How can I be sure to only match 'my name' and not 'name' in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `String.prototype.match()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()` functions:

```js
function checkMandatoryWords(str, wordSet) {
    var result = Object.keys(wordSet).reduce(function (r, k) {
        var m = str.match(new RegExp('\\b' + k + '\\b', 'g'));
        r[k] = m? m.length : 0; // writing the number of occurrences
        if (m && m.length !== wordSet[k]) r.Success = false;

        return r;
    }, {Success: true});

    return result;
}

var str = "No depending be convinced in unfeeling he. \
Excellence she unaffected and too sentiments her.\
    Rooms he doors there ye aware in by shall.\
    Education remainder in so cordially.\
    His remainder and own dejection daughters sportsmen.\
    Is easy took he shed to kind.  ",

    wordSet = {Rooms: 1, Excellence: 2, Education: 1, House: 1};

console.log(checkMandatoryWords(str, wordSet));
```